# Select count from three tables and group by one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in which I want to group by DateStart DateEnd and a foreign key and count rows

table 1  :

```
start             end           FK

10/01/2014    12/01/2014    5
10/01/2014    13/01/2014    5


table 2
10/01/2014    12/01/2014    5
10/01/2014    13/01/2014    6

table 3 

10/01/2014    12/01/2014    5
10/01/2014    13/01/2014    7


Result

10/01/2014    12/01/2014    5     3 (rows)
10/01/2014    13/01/2014    5     1
10/01/2014    13/01/2014    6     1
10/01/2014    13/01/2014    7     1
```

EDIT : 
this is my attempt (for the two first tables) which does not work as exepected:

```
SELECT     query.IDchild as IDchild,
       Count(query.Number) as Number,
       query.DateStart as DateStart,
       query.DateEnd as DateEnd
(SELECT     RES.IDchild as IDchild,
       Count(RES.Number) as Number,
       RES.DateStart as DateStart,
       RES.DateEnd as DateEnd
FROM [dbo].[VA_R] as RES
WHERE (condition)
GROUP BY RES.IDchild  ,RES.DateStart,RES.DateEnd

Union all

SELECT     RES_o.IDchild as IDchild,
       Count(RES_o.Number) as Number,
       RES_o.DateStart as DateStart,
       RES_o.DateEnd as DateEnd
FROM [dbo].[VA_R_o] as RES_o
WHERE (condition)
GROUP BY RES_o.IDchild  ,RES_o.DateStart,RES_o.DateEnd, RES_o.PK_R) as query

GROUP BY RESqueryo.IDchild  ,query.DateStart,query.DateEnd
```

Comment: UNION ALL, group by on the result. Besides, it's columns, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.start, T.end, T.FK, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT start, end, FK
    FROM YourTable1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT start, end, FK
    FROM YourTable2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT start, end, FK
    FROM YourTable3
) AS T
GROUP BY T.start, T.end, T.FK
```

That should do it. First union all results and only then group by relevant fields. As per said in comments.